# Assign a value to a variable after the fact

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I am just learning and messing around with the built-in Chrome console. Please forgive my structuring. Is there a better area I can ask these beginner questions?

There are two variations that I cannot get to work:

If I am not interested in learning JavaScript, and input a 'no' response, I want a new prompt to show that assigns a `newInterest` variable, then proceeds to alert 'That is great'.

```js
var interestLevel = prompt('Hello, are you interested in learning JavaScript?')
if (interestLevel == "yes") {
  alert('Wonderful, welcome!')
}
if (interestLevel == "no") {
  var newInterest = prompt('Then what are you interested in?')
}
```

The second one should end after a 'yes' response, but it actually goes on to ask the second prompt which should not be the case.

```js
var interestLevel = prompt('Hello, are you interested in learning JavaScript?')
if (interestLevel == "yes") {
  alert('Wonderful, welcome!')
}
if (interestlevel == "no") {
  alert('That sucks')
}
/* press ok to make the box go away so that the next prompt below will show up */
var newInterest = prompt('Then what are you interested in?')
```

EDIT: I fixed everything based on everyone's suggestions. My next goal would be to figure out how to make the below a function.

```
var interestLevel = prompt('Hello, are you interested in learning JavaScript?')
if (interestLevel == "yes") {
  alert('Wonderful, welcome!')
}
else if (interestLevel == "no") {
  alert('That sucks')
  /* press ok to make the box go away so that the next prompt below will show up */
  var newInterest = prompt('Then what are you interested in? html? css?')
if (newInterest === "html"){alert('let\'s get started with html!')}
else if (newInterest === "css"){alert('I don\'t know css')
}
    else {alert('please input css or html')}
}
```

Comment: why don't you put the second prompt inside if condition only?

Comment: `The second one should end after a 'yes' response`  What makes you think it should end?..

Comment: Why was this question downvoted? The OP provided a code sample, explained his problem, and stated what both the expected and actual results were.

Comment: @Keith 

What I mean by end after a 'yes' response, is that the second snip of code, when I run this in the Chrome console, after inputting a 'yes', it will return the alert "Wonderful, welcome!". Then it will do something illogical which proceeds to ask "Then what are you interested in", in which this specific alert should only be returned if inputted 'no'. Does that make sense?

Comment: `Then it will do something illogical`,  Well not really, it's always going to do `Then what are you interested in?`, it has no condition attached to it, so will always run after the previous alert, whatever that may be.  If you only want to to appear after the `That sucks`, then place that code inside the same `{ }`, or check the condition again.

Comment: @SelflessCrustacean To make it a function, just wrap the code in `function funcName() { }` and call it when you want it to run: `funcName();`. If you need more detail than that, you should probably start a new question.

Comment: @SelflessCrustacean See the update in my answer below for what it would look like as a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues here:

1. To have the second prompt (`newInterest`) only be displayed if the first answer is "no," move it into the `if (interestlevel == "no")` code block.
2. Your variable case doesn't always match.  `interestlevel` in the above `if` statement should be changed to `interestLevel`.

See this example:

```js
var interestLevel = prompt('Hello, are you interested in learning JavaScript?')
if (interestLevel == "yes") {
  alert('Wonderful, welcome!')
}
if (interestLevel == "no") {
  alert('That sucks')
  /* press ok to make the box go away so that the next prompt below will show up */
  var newInterest = prompt('Then what are you interested in?')
}
```

It doesn't really matter here, but with larger scripts, you could replace your second `if` statement with an `else if` statement, which would only be run if the first `if` statement returns `false`. That way, if the first condition is `true`, the second `if` statement won't be checked at all (because its result wouldn't matter) and might save you a few nanoseconds.

**UPDATE:**

If you want to make this code into a function, wrap it in a function statement, like this:

```
function myFunction() {
  var interestLevel = prompt('Hello, are you interested in learning JavaScript?')
  if (interestLevel == "yes") {
    alert('Wonderful, welcome!')
  }
  if (interestLevel == "no") {
    alert('That sucks')
      /* press ok to make the box go away so that the next prompt below will show up */
    var newInterest = prompt('Then what are you interested in?')
  }
}
```

and then call it, like this:

```
myFunction();
```

Answer (score 0):

Prompt only if the person answered **no** previously.

```js
var interestLevel = prompt('Hello, are you interested in learning JavaScript?')
if (interestLevel == "yes") {
  alert('Wonderful, welcome!')
}
if (interestlevel == "no") {
  alert('That sucks')
}
/* press ok to make the box go away so that the next prompt below will show up*/
if(interestLevel == "no")
    var newInterest = prompt('Then what are you interested in?')
```

or this will also work, depends on how you prefer to organize your code.

```js
var interestLevel = prompt('Hello, are you interested in learning JavaScript?')
if (interestLevel == "yes") {
  alert('Wonderful, welcome!')
}
if (interestlevel == "no") {
  alert('That sucks');
  var newInterest = prompt('Then what are you interested in?')
}
/*press ok to make the box go away so that the next prompt below will show up */
```

Comment: You have your comment tags backward.

Comment: LOL thanks, I have no idea how the hell that happened

Comment: @phiter It looks like my problem was missing the alert('That sucks') after the if, and instead dived head first into assigning a new variable prompt. Now to pick some brains, Say if I didn't want this alert to show up in the first place? If after immediately receiving a 'no' response, I want the user to input another interest without seeing the 'that sucks' alert?

Comment: You can just add it to the prompt. Something like: `var newInterest = prompt('That sucks...\nThen what are you interested in?')`

Comment: You cannot close the prompt by yourself. It requires direct user interaction.